# Git hub remote repo not reflecting changes on local drive

Tags: git, github

I'm new to git hub, so set up my remote repo without cloning the ssh key. I'm now trying to get the files on my local drive to save in my github repo. It's not working.

When I run, git `ls-files` in my command line, I see a long list of files that I need to add. However, when I run, the standard commands `git add .` and `git staus` I get the messsage: 'nothing to commit, working tree clean.'

I clearly have a lot to commit and push. I have one branch, `master` so this isn't an issue with branches. When I run `remote -v` I get the github repo that I would like to save files to. SO, not sure what's going on. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you run `git push`?

Comment: What do you get for `git ls-files -t`? Do all the files have an `H` in the first column?